# Self-complementary graphs having constant vertex degree

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples

A self-complementary graph $G$ on $n$ vertices is one which is isomorphic to its complementary graph $\bar{G}.$ Some such graphs, for example the cyclic graph on $5$ vertices, have the same degree for each vertex. I'm interested in examples of these. It's fairly easy to show in this situation one needs $n=4k+1.$

If such $n$ are also prime, I have a construction of an example based on a primitive root for $n.$ I'm wondering about composite $n=4k+1.$ Are there any of these for which a constant degree self-complementary graph exists? The first composite case is $n=9,$ next is $n=21,$ etc. Of interest would be an edample in one of these composite cases, or an impossibility proof, even for a few low values of $n.$

I tried it for $n=9$ and couldn't find one. Added note: I would like to assume $G$ is connected. (thisn comes from an example in a comment)

Comment: @HarryRichman I *do* want to assume $G$ is connected. Alex-- I couldn't understsand the linked material, and found none there with $n$ composite-- did I miss these?

Comment: I didn’t look at Rao’s paper. I briefly googled for self-complementary regular graphs and found that MSE question. Another found link I added to it in a comment. Also I found a theorem in “[Self-complementary strongly regular graphs  revisited](http://www.math.colostate.edu/~betten/COCOA15/TALKS/Ferenc_Szollosi.pdf)” by Ferenc Szöllősi and Patric Östergård claimimg that all self-complementary strongly regular graphs are known up to $n\le  49$.

Comment: @HarryRichman A self-complementary graph will **always** be connected, because $G$ disconnected implies $G^c$ connected for any graph $G$.  The complement of two disjoint edges is a $4$-cycle, so it's not self-complementary.

Comment: @ErickWong of course, thanks! deleted my comment to avoid further confusion [the last person who corrected me deleted their comment]

Comment: @coffeemath For $n=9$ have you tried using the primitive root for $GF(9)$?

Comment: @ErickWong Yes I tried using a primitive root mod 9 but its powers are missing some of the vertices so my method didn't work.

Comment: @coffeemath No, $GF(9)$ is not the same as $\mathbb Z_9$.  You could take $GF(9) \simeq \mathbb Z_3[x]/(x^2+2)$ which has the squares $\{\pm1, \pm x\}$, and form a Cayley graph from that.

Comment: Eric-- Will have a look at that.

Comment: @coffeemath Oops, I meant to use $x^2+1$ which is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_3$, instead of $x^2+2 = (x+1)(x+2)$.  I might have miscalculated the squares also, but I think it should work out okay :).

Comment: @ErickWong I finished going through your approach using $GF(9),$ and it works with my method, where in place of a primitive root use odd powers of a generator of the order 8 nonzero elements of the field. Thanks for your hint-- it would work for any prime power. Still remaining are then numbers $n=4k+1$ which are not prime powers, such as $n=21.$ I don't have a concrete way to work these cases...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of a regular self-complementary graph $G$ of order $9.$

The vertices of $G$ are $u_0,\ u_1,\ u_2,\ u_3,\ v_0,\ v_1,\ v_2,\ v_3,\ w.$

The edges of $G$ are $u_0w,\ u_2w,\ v_1w,\ v_3w,\ u_0u_1,\ u_2u_3,\ v_0v_1,\ v_2v_3,\ u_0u_2,\ v_1v_3,\ u_0v_0,\ u_2v_2,\ u_1v_2,\ u_3v_0,\ u_1v_0,\ u_3v_2,\ u_1v_3,\ u_3v_1.$

You can easily verify that the graph is $4$-regular; the neighborhoods are:
$N(u_0)=\{u_1,\ u_2,\ v_0,\ w\}$
$N(u_1)=\{u_0,\ v_0,\ v_2,\ v_3\}$
$N(u_2)=\{u_0,\ u_3,\ v_2,\ w\}$
$N(u_3)=\{u_2,\ v_0,\ v_1,\ v_2\}$
$N(v_0)=\{u_0,\ u_1,\ u_3,\ v_1\}$
$N(v_1)=\{u_3,\ v_0,\ v_3,\ w\}$
$N(v_2)=\{u_1,\ u_2,\ u_3,\ v_3\}$
$N(v_3)=\{u_1,\ v_1,\ v_2,\ w\}$
$N(w)=\{u_0,\ u_2,\ v_1,\ v_3\}$

The map $u_i\mapsto u_{i+1},\ v_i\mapsto v_{i+1},\ w\mapsto w$ (indices modulo $4$) is an anti-automorphism of $G,$ showing that $G$ is isomorphic to its complement.

Comment: Thanks. I like the symmetry of this example (+1, accept )